# Picture upload to PHP server doesn't work on a real iOS device

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, image

I have a problem to upload some pictures on my web server from the iPhone/ipad. Indeed, my code works really well on the simulator iPhone on the MAC but on a real device, it doesn't work, pictures are not uploaded on my server. I don't know where is the problem and why it works on the simulator and not on my device.
I have this code in objc and i call a php file to save image to the server.

the objective c code :

```
NSData *storeData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pictureItem, 90); 
NSString *URLString = @"http://url_example/upload.php"; //call upload.php

NSMutableURLRequest *request  = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%d.jpg\"\r\n", idItem] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:storeData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
```

The php file is here :

```
<?php
    $uploaddir = './';      //Uploading to same directory as PHP file
    $file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    $uploadFile = $file;
    $newName = $uploadDir . $uploadFile;


    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";
    } else {
        echo "Temp file not uploaded. \r\n";
    }

    if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']> 10000000) {
        exit("Your file is too large."); 
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {
        $postsize = ini_get('post_max_size');   //Not necessary, I was using these
        $canupload = ini_get('file_uploads');    //server variables to see what was 
        $tempdir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');   //going wrong.
        $maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    }
?>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm assuming your URL isn't `http://url_example/upload.php`  You might not want to pass `nil` in for the error and response of the `NSURLConnection` to find out what's going on.

Comment: when i print the $_FILES, i have the following part :

file : </br>Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => 5.jpg
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)

and on the simulator, everything is alright..

Comment: With a var_dump($_FILES), i have this result :
array(1) {
  ["userfile"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "7.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(1)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }

Comment: Maybe you can use Fiddler or Wireshark to capture at what the simulator sends and what the real device sends, then compare the two captures to see what is different.

Comment: You should post better logs, what is the server seeing?

Comment: try to put [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; .. after your [request setHTTPBody:body];

Answer (score 0):

Double check the case of your image filename. The simulator usually will forgive a file-case discrepancy, but a device usually won't.

For example, if you have a file in your project called `Cat.png`, and in your code you reference the resource as `cat.png` (lower case 'c'), it often will work in the simulator but not on a device.

Comment: I checked this and the problem is not here. The filename is exactly the same, no problem of lower case, nothing..